How can I prevent a 120VAC solenoid valve from resetting my ATMEGA328?
I'm using an ATMEGA328 running Arduino code to control a relay which uses a 5V signal to switch a 120 VAC solenoid. I added a flyback diode to the relay which fixed an earlier reset problem, but I'm not sure what I need to do with the AC solenoid--about 20% of the time when the coil is no longer energized, the circuit resets. Here's a schematic of the current configuration. I'm pretty new to this sort of thing, so any advice is helpful!


Do you have no capacitance near the VCC pin of the AVR? I would suggest a few different values in parallel, like 0.1uF, 1uF, and 10uF placed near the VCC pin(s).

what do you mean by AC solenoid?

@vicatcu there's a 10 uF capacitor on the 5V signal that goes to the board (upper right). Should I add the others between the +5V and GND rails on my protoboard, or do I really need to put them up against the uc?

@jsotola the solenoid is a nass magnet 116-030-0017 solenoid that is driven by 120 V 60 Hz 33 VA.

The problem might be partly schematics design (complete lack of bypass caps) and PCB design (not shown so unknown). Post the PCB design too.

You want decoupling capacitors near the IC regardless of bulk capacitance on your board to deal with high frequency power demand fluctuations

Most likely this is a layout problem that has an issue with ground path/ground bouncing. Hard to tell without layout analysis for power path versus signal ground path.

As well as mitigating the EMI at the contact, you can consider using a better design of relay. A proxy for coil-contact coupling is coil-contact breakdown voltage, which is only 1500VAC in that relay. Relays with 4kVAC coil-contact rating have lower coupling at the expense of a bit more coil current.
For example, this one from the same Chinese manufacturer SRD-16 series has 10kV impulse and 4kV AC rating.
Probably also your PCB layout could use some work, and possibly a ground plane (4-layer) if you don't have that already. Also, have no wires that go directly from off the board to the MCU (other than the power lines).

Contact arcing is a notorious source of EMI, and switching an inductive load guarantees arcing at least some of the time.
While this does indicate you have schematic and/or layout issues on your board, the relay is still a strong source, and can be mitigated.
Consider adding a snubber across the contacts, or a MOV.  Typical values would be 100Ω + 0.1µF, or a 7mm 130VAC MOV.

So I should just put a 100 ohm resistor and a 0.1 uF capacitor in series between the contacts on the relay? I can give that a shot and see what happens

@JakeNixon When someone says "across" it's synonymous with "in parallel with" in electrical engineering speak

@JakeNixon: Yes, the standard snubber is one pin of the relay contact connected to the resistor, the other leg of the resistor connected to the capacitor, and the other leg of the capacitor connected to the other pin of the relay contact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber
